# How to disallow requests that have no Origin header, or are not from allowed Origin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

Using .Net Core 3.1 I need to disallow CORS requests, except from the whitelisted origins.
I have the CorsAllowedOrigins coming in from the configuration. There is also the option to set CorsAllowAll from configuration.

I have this in ConfigureServices:

```
        var corsAllowAll = bool.Parse(config["CorsAllowAll"]);
        var corsAllowHosts = config["CorsAllowedOrigins"];

        var splitOrigins = corsAllowHosts.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            if (corsAllowAll)
            {
                Log.Information("Cors Allowing: AnyOrigin");
                options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_POLICY,
                    builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Information($"Cors Allowing: {string.Join(',', splitOrigins)}");
                options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_POLICY,
                    builder => { builder.WithOrigins(splitOrigins); });
            }
        });
```

And in the Startup Configure method I have :

```
        app.UseCors(CORS_POLICY);
        

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        { 
            endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(CORS_POLICY);
        });
```

But it is not disallowing CORS requests.

If the origin is not set at all, it allows everything.

If the origin is set and not on the list I see

```
[11:38:51 INF] CORS policy execution failed.
[11:38:51 INF] Request origin http://google.com does not have permission to access the resource.
```

Yet the request is still executed and returns the requested data.

Why is the CORS policy not applied to the request?

Do I need to add the `[EnableCors("CORS_POLICY")]` annotation on all the methods?

I thought the `endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(CORS_POLICY)` would apply to all the endpoints.

How can I get it to block the requests, if Origin is not set, or is not on the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, your requirement is that you need to set different cors policy for different scenario. So I think you can set cors policy like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "allowAll",
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
                          });
        options.AddPolicy(name: "mypolicy",
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                  "http://www.contoso.com");
                          });
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

In Configure method:
if(xxx){
    app.UseCors("mypolicy");
}else{
    app.UseCors("allowAll");
}
```

this code worked for me and you may hardcode origins in startup first for test purpose. In my test scenario, when I used `allowAll` policy, my request from `http://127.0.0.1:8848` can call api successfully, but when I use `mypolicy`, I met cors error.

Comment: Thanks, that is basically the same as what I'm doing.  The problem is I can see in the server log that the CORS policy failed, but the browser still get all the data.

Comment: Could you pls show us your cors policy but not in format of `string.Join(',', splitOrigins`? According to your description, it seemed that your `allow all` policy worked but another policy failed so that other site can get all data. If none of the policy work, other site shouldn't get data...

Comment: By the way, can you put the `if else` into `Configure` method when call `app.useCors()` but not use it in `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but despite some minor differences in our logic, the CORS policy is correct and being applied. In the logs, "CORS Policy execution failed" when the Origin is not on the list.  And the returned data does not have the "Acess-Control-Allow-Origin" header set.  It does set this header if the origin matches the list.  The issues are that the method still executes on the server, which I have learned CORS will not prevent anyway, and it's up to the Browser to honor the headers. CORS is not the right tool for this job, so I will use an IP whitelist instead.